# animation does not start in actionscript 3.0 (flash cc)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, timeline

I'm very new to using flash and actionscript 3.

I've created an animation in my timeline which works when I test the scene & play. However, when I get to testing the movie, a lot of the scenes fail to start the animation.

I've put some basic code into my actionscript which are the basic gotoandstop buttons to allow me to go to another scene.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Your question is too vague and you're not likely to get any help if you don't give us more details. We can't help you if we don't know:
1) what the issue is
2) what you did and tried
Either provide your files or code or explain your problem in a better way and you will get the help you need.

Comment: Without seeing any code, or knowing what it is you're doing, nobody is going to be able to answer your question. It would be like someone telling you their car won't start, and expecting you to know what's wrong with it just by looking at it. To know the problem you have to show enough so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Id say that using the built in 'scenes' at all in Flash are a bad idea(ever). You can do this much easier by creating each of your animations in their own MovieClips and placing those clips on their own frames on the main timeline, then simply using gotoAndStop() on your buttons to navigate between the frames you have your animation MovieClips on. - Good Luck!